Best book for stochastic analysis on manifolds
I know there is a book by Emery on Stochastic calculus on manifolds but are there any other books/online notes with an easier exposition of the subject? Any reference will be highly appreciated.

There is the book of Hsu stochastic analysis on manifolds. My supervisor didn't like it too much, but still suggested it to me as it one of the few recent books on the subject. Only thing if you go with that is to be careful, as it looks like some of the proofs contains some mistakes (this is what my supervisor told me when I had to read it)

As mentioned in the comments, "Stochastic Analysis on Manifolds" by Hsu is a worthwhile resource to consider. For context, the book has the following description on Google Books:

Probability theory has become a convenient language and a useful tool in many areas of modern analysis. The main purpose of this book is to explore part of this connection concerning the relations between Brownian motion on a manifold and analytical aspects of differential geometry. A dominant theme of the book is the probabilistic interpretation of the curvature of a manifold.

